# Omnifaces: o:socket with o:commandScript or f:ajax and avoid ajax request

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I have the following codes, which are doing the same:

1. Option1:

   <o:socket channel="notificationChannel"
   user="#{loginBean.currentEmployee.id}" scope="session"
   onmessage="notificationLoadScript">
   </o:socket>
   <h:form id="notificationPushTopbarForm">
   <o:commandScript name="notificationLoadScript"
   actionListener="#{topbarMenuController.loadNotification()}"
   render=":notificationLink" />
   </h:form>
2. Option2

   ```
    <h:form>
    <o:socket channel="notificationChannel" scope="session">
        <f:ajax event="notificationLoadScript" listener="#{topbarMenuController.loadNotification()}" render=":notificationLink" disabled="true"/>
    </o:socket>
   ```

   </h:form>

The code is working fine, but my issue is I have a Primefaces ajaxStatus Dialog which will be invoked....

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()"
    onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()">
```

Is there any possibility to disable in the <o:commandScript or <f:ajax the ajax request, which is possibile in Primefaces with global="false" ?

Many thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to avoid an ajax request. You want to avoid the `<p:ajaxStatus>` being triggered.

Use `<p:ajax global="false">` instead of `<f:ajax>`.

See also its [vdldoc](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/8.0/primefaces-p/ajax.html):

> `global`
>
> Global ajax requests are listened by ajaxStatus component, setting global to false will not trigger ajaxStatus.

Comment: ok, but how should be the "event" than? Like <p:ajax event="notificationLoadScript" listener="#{topbarMenuController.loadNotification()}" update=":notificationLink" global="false" ?